# What does bash -d means and do?

Tags: bash, docker

I have a -d option in a bash script but I dont what it does

```
cp -r ${version} ${version}tm
[ -d "latest-oi" ] rm latest-oi #line 35
[ -d "latest-tm" ] rm latest-tm #line 36
ln -sf "${version}" latest-oi
ln -sf "${version}tm" latest-tm
```

and when I execute the script I have this error message, I don't know why

```
./script.sh: line 35: [: missing `]'
./script.sh: line 36: [: missing `]'
```

I would like to know what -d means and what it does and why there is an error when the script is executed, Thanks

Comment: This might help: `help test | grep -- -d`

Comment: this should be on [unix.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any `-d` option to your **bash**, but to the command `[`.  See *man test* for this command. If you want to have two commands in the same line, you have use a command separator between them. Valid command separators are a newline, a `;`, a `&&` or a `||`.

If you write a

```
[ -d "latest-oi" ] && rm latest-oi
```

it means that the `rm` is executed if `[` returns exit code zero. Another way to write it would be

```
test -d latest-oi && rm latest-oi
```

If you would use a `||` instead, the `rm` would be executed whenever `[` returns non-zero exit code.